# Consolidate reverse-dns and dns.ptr?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have 12 questions tagged [reverse-dns](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/reverse-dns) (the tag, itself is undefined).

We have a new tag [dns.ptr](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dns.ptr), with a wiki excerpt.  This tag has only been applied to two questions so far.  There are 132 questions containing `PTR` or `PTR record`, but I haven't gone through them in detail to see how many would warrant the new [dns.ptr](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dns.ptr) tag (or the [reverse-dns](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/reverse-dns) tag).

One of the two [dns.ptr](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dns.ptr) questions is also tagged with [reverse-dns](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/reverse-dns).  Of the 132 questions, 6 are tagged [reverse-dns](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/reverse-dns).

Technically, reverse-DNS refers to the lookup process while PTR refers to the tool to accomplish it, although reverse-DNS can be used generically to include all aspects of the process.  Some questions are about the lookup and some are about dealing with the PTR records, themselves, not necessarily using them to perform a lookup.

But the two are closely related and it seems like it would be beneficial to associate them in some way to facilitate tagging questions and minimize slop and duplication.  Possibilities:

- Keep separate tags and provide usage guidance in the wiki excerpts.  This will result in some dual tagging, which might attract additional answerers.  It will also result in blurred usage, which will eventually dilute the value of the tags and need cleanup.
- Synonomize the tags.  [reverse-dns](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/reverse-dns) would probably be the better primary tag because it's the more inclusive one.  This would eliminate dual tagging.

Either way, it's useful to have a tag that pops up when the user thinks "PTR" and looks for a tag.  This should probably be driven by the users who are the most involved with the subject matter.  Can we get some input?

Comment: There is also [tag:ptr] although that looks like in will be deleted (no questions).

Comment: @DavidPostill, yeah, that was the original tag, but there are a number of things that acronym could stand for, so I replaced it with the [dns.ptr] tag.